# Не срабатывает пагинатор в классе ListView

Tags: python, django

Не срабатывает пагинатор в классе ListView, делал все по документации, посмотрел пару статей и все выглядит так же как у меня, но почему-то на сайте выводится полный список статей на одной странице.

Код views

```
class MoviesHome(ListView):
model = Movies
template_name = 'movies/movies_home.html'
context_object_name = 'movies'
paginate_by = 10

def get_queryset(self):
    return Movies.objects.filter(type_item='movie').order_by('-date')
```

Код html

```
    <div class='features'>    
    <h1> Movies</h1>       
    <div class='movie_grid'>  
        {% for movie in movies %}
            <div class='grid-item'>      
                <a href='{{movie.get_absolute_url}}'><h1 class="movie_title">{{movie.title}}</h1> 
                <img src="{{movie.poster.url}}" class="poster" alt="Poster {{movie.title}} {{movie.year}}"></a>          
            </div>      
        {% endfor %}    
   </div>
    <div class="pagination">
        <p>
            <span class="step-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}

                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if page_obj.has_other_pages %}
<nav aria-label="...">
    <ul class="pagination">

        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for p in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}

        {% if page_obj.number == p %}
        <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
           <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ p }}">{{ p }} <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
        </li>
        {% elif p > page_obj.number|add:-3 and p < page_obj.number|add:3 %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ p }}">{{ p }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}

    </ul>
</nav>
{% endif %}
```

у меня так работает

Comment: А там ничего с тех времен не поменялось? По вашей ссылке обсуждают версию джанго 1.3., я брал пример из документации к версии 4